# Get end of the day today in MySQL to compare against

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

I have this query:

```
CASE 
WHEN NOW() < `Rank`.`StartDate` THEN "Pending" 
WHEN NOW() > `Rank`.`StartDate` && NOW() < `Rank`.`EndDate` THEN "Active" 
WHEN NOW() > `Rank`.`EndDate` THEN "Expired" 
ELSE "Invalid"
END
```

Now the problem is in this line:

```
WHEN NOW() > `Rank`.`EndDate` THEN "Expired"
```

And the value of `EndDate` is like `2017-11-16 00:00:00`. Now this will return `Expired` based on this value, but how do I write it so, that it will return `Expired` after `NOW()` = `2017-11-16 23:59:59`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to only compare the date part and ignore the time of day:

```
CASE 
WHEN DATE(NOW()) < `Rank`.`StartDate`
     THEN "Pending" 
WHEN DATE(NOW()) >= `Rank`.`StartDate` && DATE(NOW()) <= `Rank`.`EndDate` 
     THEN "Active" 
WHEN DATE(NOW()) > `Rank`.`EndDate`
     THEN "Expired" 
ELSE "Invalid"
END
```